# How can I detect if a UITableView is being edited?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a UITableView and I want to detect if it is being edited. I want to hide some UILabel's that are on my cell when the user is editing. Where would I do this?

I tried:

```
- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state
{
    switch (state) {
        case UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask:
            priceLabel.hidden = YES;
            changeLabel.hidden = YES;
            break;
        case UITableViewCellStateDefaultMask:
            priceLabel.hidden = NO;
            changeLabel.hidden = NO;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

But the - for delete don't show up and neither do the icons that allow me to re-arrange cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot super. My bad.

```
[super willTransitionToState:state];
```

Comment: Is this the answer to your question?

Comment: Thank you so much, I wanted to disable access to my cell buttons, whilst the user was in edit mode. This fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The better approach is to use:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

This `UITableViewDelegate` method will hit when editing is about to begin & let you know for which row that's happening.